# PHP - Autocomplete on input tag

Tags: php, mysql, textbox, autofill

Google has an autofill function on any website. I wonder if it is possible if you could recreate this on your own website (eg. Autofill when website is loading). I want this autofill function implemented on my website. The data it gets should be coming from a database. What would be the most efficient way to be doing this?

Comment: `<input type="text" value="<?= $aValueFromMyDatabase ?>">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Value** Attribute = What is physically in the input box

The **Placeholder** Attribute = An input hint, as soon as a user types in the input box it disapears.

Use them like:

```
<input type="text" value="<?=$data['username']>">
```

Or:
    ">

Also, disable autofill with `autocomplete="off"`

[Source for autocomplete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)